# android getSupportActionBar().setTitle not working when Json parsing using volley

Tags: android, json, android-volley

my purpose is setting title using String from json parsing.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
     getSupportActionBar().setTitle(title);}
```

it is working... but.. in this case..

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);
    int target_id=getIntent().getIntExtra("id",1);
    Postview("my name","my mail",target_id,this);}


private void Postview(final String name, final String email,final int target_id,final Context context) {

    StringRequest strReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            Config.URL_POST_VIEW+"/"+target_id, new Response.Listener<String>() {

        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {

                JSONObject jObj = new JSONObject(response);
                boolean error = jObj.getBoolean("error");
                if (!error) {
                    getSupportActionBar().setTitle(jObj.getString("title"));


                } else {
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // JSON error
            }

        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {

        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        }
    });
}
```

I erased other unimportant code...

json parsing has no problem.

everything works well except setTitle...

Comment: it is not a issue of volley ,  as i can see you are getting a response after your activity is been drawn.   So Either call web service previously or created it after getting the response from server .. will solve the issue

Comment: @Punit Sharma: you're true! I guessed it is not problem of json. before startActivity() I added putExtraIntent(title) and it is solved. Thank you sir! 気持ちいい

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to update the UI (the toolbar tilte) on a background thread which is not allowed. You can update the user interface only on UI thread.

Tip:

If you can add the crash report to your question then that would help everyone to give the right suggestions quickly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Library for the ActionBar then use

```
getSupportActionBar().setTitle(jObj.getString("title"));
```

If you are not then use

```
getActionBar().setTitle(jObj.getString("title"));
```